# What differs in the destruction of stl::unordered_map and stl::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am looking for a more in detail answer, rather than UB is UB.

I have a piece of legacy code that I know is the culprit of an exception. We previously memset a vector, and once it was changed to an unordered_map it threw an exception on destruction. What in the source code makes memsetting a vector differ from an unordered_map? They both interact with contiguous memory...

In our code we have this. (I apologize for pseudo code, but the point should still be understandable...)

```
class B
{
    std::vector<CustomObject> vect;
};

struct STRUCT_A
{
    B b;
};
```

Later on we do this...

```
STRUCT_A m_struct_a;
memset(&m_struct_a, 0, sizeof(STRUCT_A));
```

This works perfectly fine even if we memset an stl::container! However, if we change class B to have a map then an exception occurs on the destructor.

```
class B
{
    std::map<CustomObject> vect;
};
```

So I thought it had to do with the vector being contiguous, so I changed it to an unordered_map

```
class B
{
    std::unordered_map<CustomObject> vect;
};
```

An exception is still thrown on the destructor. I thought it was pretty interesting, and thought it was a good question to ask...

Comment: You know the reason.  It is undefined behavior.  So with a vector it happens to "work", but it still doesn't work since you have ill-formed code.

Comment: "This works perfectly fine even if we `memset` an STL container" - NO.

Comment: `memset`ting anything other than a POD is just a creative way of exploding your program

Comment: _Yes I understand memsetting an object causes undefined behavior_ So.. What is the question? Undefined behavior is undefined. You may observe different results when using different compilers. Standard makes no guarantees that it would work in one specific way.

Comment: That's just not how you clear *any* standard container. You should not even *need* a `memset` to "initialize" a structure, instead write a *constructor* which does what needs to be done, and for the example structures you show then *nothing* needs to be done, at all. The vector will start out empty.

Comment: "Yes I understand [this] causes undefined behavior" and "why does it work for a vector and not the other containers" doesn't go together. UB is UB.

Comment: Just because it *seems* to work with one container and one compiler on one platform does *not* mean it *works*. It may break randomly if *anything* changes or it may actually currently be breaking code *elssewhere* in your program. Don't rely on UB. Just don't.

Comment: I agree with your points on not to do it, but I think the question is still valid for everyone. Understanding why it causes undefined behavior seems beneficial instead of just saying "Because I said so"...

Comment: You didn't ask that, you asked why the code "worked", not why it's UB.

Comment: It was updated.

Comment: It causes UB because you'd zero out pointers about to be deleted? Try `delete (int*)0;`

Comment: @Taztingo Well.. The answer **isn't** "Because I said so", it is "Because **standard** says so". And because of that, compilers are free to implement UB cases as they feel like it.

Comment: -8 is particularly harsh for a well-written question. Please don't downvote just because you feel the question is obvious.

Comment: @PasserBy You can delete null pointers.

Comment: Using a different compiler might cause a crash with vector as well. How containers are structured internally and what their destructors need to clean up is completely implementation defined, so your question is not answerable for anything other than a very specific toolchain. Even then, why does it matter? You could certainly make your own class that will crash if memset, so assume the container is the same.

Comment: @Barry That's super news to me

Comment: @PasserBy Yes I understand that... This has been in legacy code for years, and it has not thrown any type of exception until it was changed from a vector to a map. I know it's not right, and it was updated to not memset. I was just curious as to what might differ in map vs vector for this to work...

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius Thanks the second part of your second comment was what I was looking for. "compilers are free to implement UB cases as they feel like it."

Seems kind of harsh to get so many downvotes, but I could have worded it better to prevent a lot of trolls.

Comment: On explaining the unexplainable (UB): A `std::vector` typically stores a pointer, a size, and a capacity. An initial configuration of `{nullptr, 0, 0}` is reasonable and will survive the memset. A `map` contains a tree-structure, where the pointers are not null. Clearing them will kill the structure.

Comment: @BoPersson Thank you, and that's what I thought. I changed it to an unordered_map. That does not contain a tree structure, and shouldn't it be identical to a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source for your implementation's containers.

In libstdc++, the destructor for `std::vector` calls `CustomObject::~CustomObject()` for each element in the range `[begin(), end())` and then deallocates the memory. Since you `memset` the `vector` to 0, `begin() == end() == 0`, the range is empty and the member's destructor is never called. Similarly, the deallocation is fine since it checks that the storage is non-null before deallocating.

In `std::map`, the destructor tries to walk the nodes of the `_Rb_tree`, which fails because the root node has null pointers. In `std::unordered_map`, the destructor calls `__builtin_memset` on the bucket array, which fails because the pointer to the array has been cleared.

Comment: This is the actual answer I was looking for thank you! An answer that goes more into the source code.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is indeed an act of absolute insanity to `::memset` an instance of a class that contains an STL container.

Thinking more generally, you can only call `memset` on an object that is *trivially copyable*. Otherwise the behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

For more details on that, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable

Comment: Calling `memset` on a trivially-copyable type might still be bad, if the object has some property that needs to be met

Comment: @PasserBy If that is the case doesn't that mean it is not trivially copyable?

Comment: @NathanOliver I'd imagine something like `class Circle`, it is trivially copyable, but its radius shouldn't ever be negative or something like that

Comment: Eh whatever, I'll just accept this. I think Algirdas Preidžius made a good point about how UB cases are compiler specific.

Comment: Out of interest, were you using StlPort for your STL library that "permitted" memset on your vector? From memory, early StlPort versions had a short buffer optimisation, which is now illegal from C++11 due to swap requirements.

Comment: I am using VS15, and it's latest compiler. I'm not sure if VS15 uses stlport, or just the normal stl library.

Comment: No, it will be using the very good C++ standard library that ships with that compiler.